# Android facebook LikeView

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook-like

**I followed all steps to set up facebook sdk
my problem is LikeView not shwon in xml even on running app on mobile**

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
    android:text="Like Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnLike" />
```

**I get this error**

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
-com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
```

Comment: Try initializing the view in Java code.

Comment: it is intialized

Comment: Have you added the compile compile link in gradle? For the Facebook sdk

Comment: yes I followed all steps to set up facebook sdk as I mentioned in my question